# How can I determine if there is an open source software for a specific purpose?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, open-source

We are going to write an entire new application for a reservation system. In this system experts specify their free time in elaborated calendar and users seek them through searched and finally reserve the expert and his time.

We prefer to find an open source program like this and try to evolve it instead of creating it from scratch. In this manner our time is saved and that open source program will be completer too.

We are a entire .NET (ASP.NET, C#, NHibernate) company.

We have same problem to find open source applications for our new projects.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I add an example: many companies like us writes workflow systems. But recently I discovered an open source workflow software called ProcessMaker (http://www.processmaker.com/) that do this perfectly. In such a case, companies could dedicate their development time to evolving this one instead of writing a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Search

Sourceforge

Google Code

**UPDATE:** There is the NerdDinners site http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/ This is an example of a basic reservation system in .NET MVC. This is not all the functionality you are looking for, but it is open source and can get you started.

Comment: But my English is not very good and I'm not very acquainted with abbreviations, expressions and idioms.

Comment: Try the one I updated in my answer.

Comment: I searched for my desired project and wrote the story in my blog: http://afsharm.blogspot.com/2010/03/searching-for-specific-open-source.html

Answer (score 2):

Also

[codeplex.com](http://codeplex.com)
[codeproject.com](http://codeproject.com)

Answer (score 1):

> We prefer to find an open source program like this and try to evolve it instead of creating it from scratch.

The openness of the source code is irrelevant here.

It's the license that it's important.

You can find a lot of GPL open-source code, but if you want to contribute to it, you'll have to stick to this license. This might not suit your company.

Comment: Please see the definition of open source (http://www.opensource.org/docs/definition.php).

Comment: Please see the definition of free software (http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-software-for-freedom.html)

Comment: I am aware of the definition of free software.  Your post is misleading because it implies the license is not a part of whether a program is open source ("The openness of the source code is irrelevant here.").

Answer (score 0):

Freshmeat.net is also useful a useful standby for finding open source software.

Answer (score 0):

Also: [ohloh.net](http://www.ohloh.net/)

*Ohloh* is a free, public directory of Free and Open Source Software and the contributors who create and maintain it. Ohloh Code is a publicly available, free code search site that indexes most of the projects in Ohloh